# Core-Plot: CPPlotSpaceDelegate methods not getting called in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, core-plot

CPPlotSpaceDelegate methods not getting called in my app.

I have tried putting delegate implementation tag in header like

```
<CPPlotSpaceDelegate,CPPlotDataSource>
```

**EDIT:**

I have even tried

`plotSpace.delegate=self;`

but does not seem to work

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change it to

`graph.defaultPlotSpace.delegate = self;`

Thanks

Pratik Goswami